# Facing an exception while accessing modals using an service

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have separated the modals as components and I wrote a service so that I can use that service and open modal from anywhere.

My service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'; 
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@Injectable()
export class MyModalsService {
    loginModalRef: BsModalRef;
    public modalService: BsModalService;
    constructor() {
    }
    openLogin() {
        this.loginModalRef= this.modalService.show(LoginComponent);
    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import  { MyModalsService } from '../modals.service';
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public _userService: UserService,
    private http: Http,
    public server:ServerService,
    public _otherservicesService: OtherservicesService,
    public global:GlobalService,
    public datepipe: DatePipe,
    public mymodal: MyModalsService,
    public router:Router) {}

    AfetrSuccessLogin() {
       this.mymodal.loginModalRef.hide();
    } 
}
```

I'm facing the below exception

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]).
```

In Terminal

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/modals.service.ts -> src/app/login/login.component.ts -> 
src/app/modals.service.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/login/login.component.ts -> 
src/app/modals.service.ts -> src/app/login/
login.component.ts
```

Comment: Have you added imports for Http, ServerService, etc used in constructor?

Comment: Ops! Sorry! you can't implement in this way.  I'm giving an idea  You have to write modal login inside of the Component. Then make a service. When the service will emit true, the modal will open. When the service will emit false, the modal will be closed. Now you can inject the service anywhere .

Comment: Did you add your service in providers list in module ?

Comment: Yes I have added. I'm able to open the modal from other component. But in login component I need to close the modal. So I'm using the service here. @NanditaAroraSharma

Comment: Can I get any sample code @RitwickDey

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is wrong way to use services in angular.
Try the following:

Your service:

```
import {Subjcet} from "rxjs/Subject";
export class YourService {
       private modalSubject:Subject<boolean>
       constructor(){
           this.modalSubject = new Subject();
       }

       getModalSubject(){
          return this.modalSubject;
       }

       afterSuccessLogin(){
          this.modalSubject.next(true);
       }
```

And in your component

```
improt {YourService} from "yourServiceDirectory";

export class YourComponent{
     constructor(private myService:YourService){
         this.myService.getModalSubject().subscribe(closeMyModal => {
               if(closeMyModal){
                    //Close your modal
               }
         })
     }
}
```

Comment: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Subject<boolean>'. And also how can I open the modal?

Comment: I edited my answer .. you can open the modal by pass false ti the subject. So in the subsribe function you can check if true means clise the modal else open it.

Comment: this.myService.getModalSubject().subscribe(openMyModal => { alert(openMyModal); }); On clicking Login button I'm not getting any alert in openLogin()

Comment: Thankyou. But How can I open the modal? Please refer https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals for opening the modal. How can use them in service

Comment: You cannot use the directive of ng-bootstrap in the service, the service should only be responsible of notify the component when to open or close the modal. the closing and opening the modal is component responsibility.